# Java selenium click override or create own

Tags: java, selenium

Hei. I have been creating automated tests with selenium, but I have ran into some issues with IE the click not working. (Seems like a common issue where the driver just freezes and it won't timeout or anything).

As a workaround I created a method which uses javascript executor to do the click instead.

```
 public static void IEClick(WebElement element) {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
  }
```

The issue I have is that I would have to rewrite all my tests in order to make them work on IE.

```
  @Test
  public void Simpletest(){

    Frontpage.SearchBox.sendKeys("DeadPool");
    Frontpage.GOButton.click();
    Frontpage.FirstREsult.click();    
  }
```

Would have to be changed to

```
  @Test
      public void Simpletest(){
   Frontpage.SearchBox.sendKeys("DeadPool");
    IEClick(Frontpage.GOButton);
    IEClick(Frontpage.FirstREsult);
}
```

This is a solution but this mean I would have to redo all my tests to handle this. Which seems a little too much. So I'm wondering is it possible to create my own click?

**Desired solution**

```
 Frontpage.FirstREsult.MyClick();
```

Where in MyClick I have already handled all the cases with different browsers etc.So I could just search and replace the click with my own click.

Answer (score 0):

1) At first you can get a browser name from capabilities and using js or native click depending on browser

`Capabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
String browserName = caps.getBrowserName();`

2) Also you can always use a js click. It's a very rare situation where you can need the native one